# Resilience4j circuit breaker actuator heath check metrics showing some negative numbers

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, resilience4j, spring-boot-2

I am using resiliance4j circuit breaker with spring boot. in the actuator health point metrics, I am seeing some disparities in as slow-calls, a slow failed calls number are coming in negative instead of positive. which is not letting my circuit breaker to open. can anyone help me the significance of this, what these negative values mean?

```
 "endpoint1":{
           "status":"UP",
           "details":{
              "failureRate":"0.0%",
              "failureRateThreshold":"50.0%",
              "slowCallRate":"0.0%",
              "slowCallRateThreshold":"50.0%",
              "bufferedCalls":3500,
              "slowCalls":0,
              "slowFailedCalls":-2682,
              "failedCalls":0,
              "notPermittedCalls":0,
              "state":"CLOSED"
           }
        }
```

Comment: Could you please create an issue in https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/issues so that we can investigate it. Please also add which version of resilience4j you are using.

Comment: Hi Rob, I have created the ticket for the issue. this issue is not visible on higher load.